# SQL - How to find which page is the first for users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by, min

I have a table like this:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| user_id  | time                                | url                              |
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1        | 02.04.2017 8:56                     | www.landingpage.com/              | 
| 1        | 02.04.2017 8:57                     | www.landingpage.com/about-us     |  
| 1        | 02.04.2017 8:58                     | www.landingpage.com/faq          |
| 2        | 02.04.2017 6:34                     | www.landingpage.com/about-us     |
| 2        | 02.04.2017 6:35                     | www.landingpage.com/how-to-order |
| 3        | 03.04.2017 9:11                     | www.landingpage.com/             |
| 3        | 03.04.2017 9:12                     | www.landingpage.com/contact      |
| 3        | 03.04.2017 9:13                     | www.landingpage.com/about-us     |
| 3        | 03.04.2017 9:14                     | www.landingpage.com/our-legacy   |
| 3        | 03.04.2017 9:15                     | www.landingpage.com/             |
+----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I want to figure out which page is the first for most users (first page a user see when he comes to the site) and count the number of times it is viewed as the first page.

Is there a way to write a query to do this? I guess I need to use

```
MIN(time)
```

in conjunction with grouping but I don't know how.

So regarding the sample I provided it should be like:

```
url                                       url_count
---------------------------------------------------
www.landingpage.com/                      2            
www.landingpage.com/about-us              1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you'll need to use the `min()` aggregate function within a subselect.

```
select
  my_table.url
from
  my_table
where
  my_table.time = (
    select
      min(t.time)
    from
      my_table t
    where
      t.user_id = my_table.user_id
  )
```

replace `my_table` with whatever your table is actually named.

---

To include how many pages the user has seen, you'll need something like this:

```
select
  my_table.url
  , (
    select
      count(t.url)
    from
      my_table t
    where
      t.user_id = my_table.user_id
  ) as url_count
from
  my_table
where
  my_table.time = (
    select
      min(t.time)
    from
      my_table t
    where
      t.user_id = my_table.user_id
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! If I get it right, in order to count the urls I need to add url grouping so the code will look like:
 `select
  my_table.url, count(my_table.url)
from
  my_table
where
  my_table.time = (
    select
      min(t.time)
    from
      my_table t
    where
      t.user_id = my_table.user_id
  )
group by my_table.url
order by my_table.url desc
`
The top row will show which url was first for most users and the total number of views. Is that correct?

Comment: @monsieurkovacs: unfortunately, no. The where clause limits it to just the minimal row. If you want to include the count, you'll need to add a sub select to the select clause.

Comment: @monsieurkovacs: I've edited the question to include a user count. Please remember to upvote answers that were helpful, and accept whichever is the most helpful :)

Comment: Now it shows the entry page visited by the user and total count of page viewed by the user. What I need is to count the total amount of entry pages (please see the updated initial post). 
I hope I'm clear enough now. 
Thanks again! 
PS I upvoted every reply but votes are not displayed as my reputation is under 15

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE time IN 
(
  SELECT min(time) 
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY url
);
```

Comment: What happens if you have two records with same min [time] record?

Comment: The person who asked question said that "I need to use MIN(time)". The answer was written according to the wishes of the person. In your condition time value must contain second or miliseconds value. I mean time should not be same for different user on same url.

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * 
    from yourtable
order by row_number() over(partition by user_id order by [time])
```

You can use outer query to get the same as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, RowN = row_number() over(partition by user_id order by [time]) from yourtable) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```